# TextField in CollectionView

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uitextfield

Есть *Collection View*, которое заполняется картинками с интернета. При нажатии на одну из этих *view*, открывается второй *ViewController* с увеличенной картинкой.

Во втором контроллере есть *UITextField*. Я сделал сохранение текста из этого поля. Когда я ввожу текст, затем сворачиваю клавиатуру, текст сохраняется нормально. Но проблема в том, что текст который я ввёл сохраняется на все текстовые поля.

Как сделать так, чтобы он сохранялся только на то поле, в которое я ввёл текст?   Дайте направление, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  yourTextField.text = nil;
  return [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseId forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/147533)